# javascript refresh page with countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how do you make the page refresh it self when countdown is 0 ?

for example, i want to make the page refresh every 10 seconds using javascript and when 5 seconds left from 10 seconds, it must be displayed on the page and counts to from 5 to 0 then refresh the page

i have tried this

```
function startChecking() {
    secondsleft -= 1e3;
    if (secondsleft <= 3e4) {
        document.getElementById("div_countdown").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("timercounter").innerHTML = Math.abs(secondsleft / 1e3) + " Seconds"
    }
}

function startschedule() {
    clearInterval(timeout);
    clearInterval(interval);
    timeout = setTimeout("window.location.href=window.location.href;", threshold);
    secondsleft = threshold;
    interval = setInterval(function() {
        startChecking()
    }, 1e3)
}

function resetTimer() {
    startschedule();
    document.getElementById("div_countdown").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("timercounter").innerHTML = ""
}
var timeout, interval;
var threshold = 108e4;
var secondsleft = threshold;
startschedule();
window.onload = function() {
    startschedule()
}
```

but it doesn't work perfectly . it does refresh the page every 18 mins and when 30 seconds left it displays on screen but the problem is, it will refresh the page and the countdown is not even on 0. it will refresh while counting from 30 seconds

Comment: Why did you put the jQuery tag on your question? I see none.

Comment: that i the code that i tried, what should i put then ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the refresh timeout and the check interval are out of sync?  Maybe instead of using a setTimeout for the refresh try and execute the refresh from the check interval when there is 0 seconds left.  Just add this to the end of your startChecking function:

```
if (secondsleft == 0){
    window.location.reload();
}
```

And then remove the timeout you set to do the refresh.

Working sample here:
https://jsfiddle.net/k3jxku4s/1/

Comment: thank you for your answer, will you edit and fix my cod please ? i don't know that much in javascript

Comment: Add this to your startChecking function:

`if (secondsleft == 0){
     window.location.reload();
}`

and you can remove the timeout you set for the refresh.